# Sitecore MVC model lost after postback

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have a page /registration that contains two forms on it.

One for registration and one for logging in.    The registration form is one controller rendering, the login form is another controller rendering.

When I load /registration the page loads correctly and the model is populated.

When I click the submit button, the Post action fires and the model is suddenly reset back to it's default state.   Shouldn't the model remain populated without having to repopulate it?

My model:

```
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MySite.Models.Items
{

    public class Registration: IRenderingModel
    {
        public Registration()
        {
            FirstName = string.Empty;
            LastName = string.Empty;
            Email = string.Empty;
            JobTitle = string.Empty;
            Company = string.Empty;
            Industry = string.Empty;
            SubIndustry = string.Empty;
            RevenueRange = string.Empty;
            Country = string.Empty;
            StateProvince = string.Empty;
            MarketoTracking = string.Empty;
            ReturnUrl = string.Empty;
        }

        public Rendering Rendering { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public Item PageItem { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string SubIndustry { get; set; }
        public string RevenueRange { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string StateProvince { get; set; }
        public string MarketoTracking { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }


        #region "Country List"
        public IEnumerable<CountryChildItem> CountryList { get; set; }
        public string CountryChildMenu { get; set; }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class CountryItem
        {
            public virtual IEnumerable<CountryChildItem> Children { get; set; }
        }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class CountryChildItem
        {
            [SitecoreId]
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

            [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
            public virtual string Path { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string Abbreviation { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string SortOrder { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion



        #region "State / Province List"
        public IEnumerable<StateProvinceChildItem> StateProvinceList { get; set; }

        public class StateProvinceItem
        {
            public virtual IEnumerable<StateProvinceChildItem> Children { get; set; }
        }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class StateProvinceChildItem
        {
            [SitecoreId]
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

            [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
            public virtual string Path { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string Abbreviation { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string ParentCountry { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string SortOrder { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion



        #region "Industry List"
        public IEnumerable<IndustryChildItem> IndustryList { get; set; }
        public string IndustryChildMenu { get; set; }


        public class IndustryItem
        {
            public virtual IEnumerable<IndustryChildItem> Children { get; set; }
        }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class IndustryChildItem
        {
            [SitecoreId]
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

            [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
            public virtual string Path { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string SortOrder { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion



        #region "Sub-industry List"
        public IEnumerable<SubIndustryChildItem> SubIndustryList { get; set; }

        public class SubIndustryItem
        {
            public virtual IEnumerable<SubIndustryChildItem> Children { get; set; }
        }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class SubIndustryChildItem
        {
            [SitecoreId]
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

            [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
            public virtual string Path { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string ParentIndustry { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string SortOrder { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion



        #region "Revenue List"
        public IEnumerable<RevenueChildItem> RevenueList { get; set; }

        public class RevenueItem
        {
            public virtual IEnumerable<RevenueChildItem> Children { get; set; }
        }

        [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
        public class RevenueChildItem
        {
            [SitecoreId]
            public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

            [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Path)]
            public virtual string Path { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

            [SitecoreField]
            public virtual string SortOrder { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion



        public void Initialize(Rendering rendering)
        {
            Rendering = rendering;
            Item = rendering.Item;
            PageItem = PageContext.Current.Item;
        }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using MySite.Analytics;
using MySite.Models.Items;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MySite.Presentation.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : AsyncController
        {

        Registration registration = new Registration();

        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult Index(string view)
            {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(view))
            {
                registration.ReturnUrl = view.Trim();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registration.ReturnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            {
                registration.ReturnUrl = Server.UrlDecode(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri ?? string.Empty);
            }
            PopulateLists();
            return PartialView(registration);
        }


        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(string RegistrationButton, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RegistrationButton))
            {
                try
                {
                    registration.FirstName = formCollection["FirstName"].Trim();
                    registration.LastName = formCollection["LastName"].Trim();
                    registration.Email = formCollection["Email"].Trim();
                    registration.JobTitle = formCollection["JobTitle"].Trim();
                    registration.Company = formCollection["Company"].Trim();
                    registration.Industry = formCollection["Industry"].Trim();
                    registration.SubIndustry = formCollection["SubIndustry"].Trim();
                    registration.RevenueRange = formCollection["RevenueRange"].Trim();
                    registration.Country = formCollection["Country"].Trim();
                    registration.StateProvince = formCollection["StateProvince"].Trim();
                    registration.MarketoTracking = formCollection["_mkt_trk"].Trim();
                    ContactManagement contactManagement = new ContactManagement();
                    contactManagement.RegisterContact(registration);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("MySite.Presentation.Controllers.RegistrationController.Index", ex, this);
                }
            }
            return PartialView();
        }


        public void PopulateLists()
        {
            ISitecoreContext sitecoreContext = new SitecoreContext();
            ISitecoreService service = new SitecoreService(sitecoreContext.Database);

            Guid countryItemID = new Guid("{2FB5AE2D-E80D-4A3D-9201-3E62E781EFCD}");
            Registration.CountryItem countryItem = service.GetItem<Registration.CountryItem>(countryItemID);
            registration.CountryList = countryItem.Children.OrderBy(l => System.Convert.ToInt32(l.SortOrder)).ThenBy(l => l.DisplayName);

            Guid stateProvinceItemID = new Guid("{6171F149-0200-4010-BF5F-5F32EAAE31B4}");
            Registration.StateProvinceItem stateProvinceItem = service.GetItem<Registration.StateProvinceItem>(stateProvinceItemID);
            registration.StateProvinceList = stateProvinceItem.Children.OrderBy(l => System.Convert.ToInt32(l.SortOrder)).ThenBy(l => l.DisplayName);

            Guid industryItemID = new Guid("{ACD77146-0530-4EEE-A477-BF8CD54B9FFE}");
            Registration.IndustryItem industryItem = service.GetItem<Registration.IndustryItem>(industryItemID);
            registration.IndustryList = industryItem.Children.OrderBy(l => System.Convert.ToInt32(l.SortOrder)).ThenBy(l => l.DisplayName);

            Guid subIndustryItemID = new Guid("{43AAABDF-9591-4F03-9894-0EAEFD1292B3}");
            Registration.SubIndustryItem subIndustryItem = service.GetItem<Registration.SubIndustryItem>(subIndustryItemID);
            registration.SubIndustryList = subIndustryItem.Children.OrderBy(l => System.Convert.ToInt32(l.SortOrder)).ThenBy(l => l.DisplayName);

            Guid revenueItemID = new Guid("{86C0FF05-5A9C-4113-BEE6-B68E19BAAB37}");
            Registration.RevenueItem revenueItem = service.GetItem<Registration.RevenueItem>(revenueItemID);
            registration.RevenueList = revenueItem.Children.OrderBy(l => System.Convert.ToInt32(l.SortOrder)).ThenBy(l => l.DisplayName);
        }


        public string GetChildList(string countryDisplayName, IEnumerable<Registration.StateProvinceChildItem> stateProvinceChildItem)
        {
            string menuString = string.Empty;
            if (stateProvinceChildItem != null)
            {
                JArray menuArray = new JArray();
                foreach (var state in stateProvinceChildItem)
                {
                    if (state.ParentCountry == countryDisplayName)
                    {
                        JValue menuItem = new JValue("{\"name\": \"" + state.DisplayName + " (" + state.Abbreviation + ")\", \"value\": \"" + state.Abbreviation + "\"}");
                        menuArray.Add(menuItem);
                    }
                }
                if (menuArray.Count > 0)
                {
                    menuString = "data-child-menu='{\"items\": " + menuArray.ToString() + "}'";
                }
            }
            return menuString;
        }


        public string GetChildList(string industryId, IEnumerable<Registration.SubIndustryChildItem> subIndustryChildItem)
        {
            string menuString = string.Empty;
            if (subIndustryChildItem != null)
            {
                JArray menuArray = new JArray();
                foreach (var subIndustry in subIndustryChildItem)
                {
                    if (subIndustry.ParentIndustry.Trim().ToUpperInvariant().Contains(industryId.Trim().ToUpperInvariant()))
                    {
                        JValue menuItem = new JValue("{\"name\": \"" + subIndustry.DisplayName + "\", \"value\": \"" + subIndustry.DisplayName + "\"}");
                        menuArray.Add(menuItem);
                    }
                }
                if (menuArray.Count > 0)
                {
                    menuString = @"data-child-menu='{""items"": " + menuArray.ToString() + "}'";
                }
            }
            return menuString;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is currently a problem with having multiple views on the same page with Sitecore MVC. You can refer to this article for more detailed description of the issue and possible resolutions -http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/09/25/sitecore-mvc-multiple-forms/ . (I have seen that you also have httpGet to the default action as well)

Comment: I upvoted your comment.   This fixed the problem.

Comment: added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a problem with Sitecore MVC and having multiple forms. I believe the problem is that you have `[HttpGet]` set to your Index action which might mess the Sitecore Routing. You can check for more problems with multiple forms in this [blog post](http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/09/25/sitecore-mvc-multiple-forms/).